# How to transform a Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, transformation, scalar

Or to ask it in a other way "How to repair a crooked Bitmap by given Parameters"

the Situation i got an Bitmap which was scanned and could be crooked so i will check it agains some known values to get all 4 (real)corners

for example:

```
                x     y                  result
TOP LEFT     ( 100 |   50)             (  0|   0)
TOP RIGHT    ( 800 |    0)             (900|   0)
BOTTOM LEFT  (  5  | 2050)             (  0|2000)
BOTTOM RIGHT (1000 | 2000)             (900|2000)
```

so how would you achieve this

i know i need:

- [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx)
- [SkewTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.skewtransform.aspx)
- [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx)
- [MatrixTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrixtransform.aspx)

but how do i use it to transform the Bitmap itself

Comment: Are you using the .NET environment by any chance?

Comment: @StevenT. maybe my english is to bad but i don't understand this question because i'm using c# with wpf (see the Tags) so what else than .NET should i use o.O?